# Missing symbols – but symbols exist?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to compile a unit testing target using googletest. While it works in one project, it is failing to link in a different project, and I'm struggling to understand why.

The `link.txt` generated by CMake:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/ATAppTests.cpp.o  -o runTests ../../src/targetLib.a ../../lib/libgtestd.a ../../lib/libgtest_maind.a ../../lib/libgmockd.a ../../lib/libgmock_maind.a ../../lib/libgmockd.a ../../lib/libgtestd.a
```

The result of running that command:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in ATAppTests.cpp.o
```

However, running `nm` indicates the symbol is there:

```
 $ nm --demangle ../../lib/libgtestd.a | grep 'MakeAndRegister'
000000000000ebe0 T testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here!

Comment: The second one wants a testing::internal::CodeLocation while the first one wants a void const * as 5th argument. Is it expected?

Comment: Yes, the `nm` call shows the symbol, but it has an additional `testing::internal::CodeLocation` argument in the function signature...

Comment: Well spotted, it seems there are different definitions in two header files. I have no idea why this is compiling ok in my other project or how this hasn't been spotted by the google test devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out another project I am using has an old gtest header embedded in it, which was being picked up instead.

https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff/blob/master/gtest/gtest.h

Answer (score 0):

I bet its the order in which you have the static libraries there!

But now that you have identified the file in which the missing function is you can start playing around a bit until it works. Once fixed it will become very obvious to you, why it had to be in that order and you will wonder, why your compiler was not smarter. You find many explanations here on stackoverflow, because many of us had this problem before :)

I can currently not try it, but this -I believe- is a promising guess:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/ATAppTests.cpp.o  -o runTests ../../src/targetLib.a ../../lib/libgtestd.a ../../lib/libgtestd.a ../../lib/libgtest_maind.a ../../lib/libgmockd.a ../../lib/libgmock_maind.a ../../lib/libgmockd.a`